# How to save navigation state between configuration changes?

Tags: jetpack-compose-navigation, android-compose

I have an android compose app that is set up with a single activity that uses NavController to navigate between screens.

However, when I rotate the screen (make a configuration change) the screen resets to the `startDestination` specified in the `NavHost`.

How can I preserve the nav state between configuration changes?

Answer (score -2):

It's quite simple, really.

The reason you keep going back to your **startDestination** is because *configuration changes destroy and recreate the current activity*.

**You need to disable activity recreation** by specifying it in your AndroidManifest.xml

For example, adding the following attribute under an activity's tag would let you rotate the screen without destroying that activity, thereby preserving your navigation state:

`android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize|screenLayout"`

##### Android Documentation Sources

1. [Handle Configuration Changes](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/runtime-changes#restrict-activity)
2. [Possible Values for the android:configChanges attribute](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element#config)